# plot() does not work with keras, eclipse and statET

Tags: r, keras, statet

I am running `keras` library from `R` under eclipse / statET / windows 10. After to fit a model, I am trying to run the following code:

```
history <- model %>% fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch = 100, epochs = 30, validation_data = validation_generator, validation_steps = 50)



jpeg(filename="figuras/history.jpg")
plot(history)
dev.off()
```

But no figure is drawn. Nevertheless, if I execute the same sententes above shown in the command line of statET, or I run the whole script from R, it works fine: could someone explain such behaviour?

Comment: Provide a reproducible data: `dput(model)`, for example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but this is my first tile I use stackoverflow, and I am not sure about how to enclose a file... dput() give me an ascii file...

Comment: You must do `dput(model)` and copy and paste the output in your question.